# How do i generate Webp preview animations using FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg, webp

So i have been generating preview animations in GIF formats using `FFMPEG`. (basically selecting a few seconds of the whole video and storing as `gif`)

however the previews that `youtube` generates in `webp` format seem way more smaller in size than what i have achieved.

Here is the command i use to generate a 3 second preview in `webp` format:

`ffmpeg -i d:\1.mp4 -lossless 0 -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:03 -s 320x180 1.webp`

But this is still larger than equivalent `gif`.

Any tips on how to reduce the output `webp` animation?

**Update**

even with max compression and min quality ffmpeg it still produces much larger `webp` outputs than what `gif2web` gives.

Comment: Is this issue resolved for you?

Answer (score 6):

decrease quality
http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#libwebp

```
-quality float
 For lossy encoding, this controls image quality. 
 For lossless encoding, this controls the effort and time spent in compression. 
 Range is 0 to 100. Default is 75.
```

[fix qscale to quality.](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/fa12d808d7239d120a3b43b6fb7e106db4e46d30)

Comment: `Please use -q:a or -q:v, -qscale is ambiguous`

Answer (score 2):

These are reasonable compression settings for an animated thumbnail.

```
-compression_level 6 -q:v 75
```

`-loop 0` if you want it to loop. Compression level ange is 0 to 6. Quality range is 0 to 100.
https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/cwebp

If you're willing to spend more time decoding, you can make more interesting thumbnails by taking short scenes from the whole video. Check out my [gist](https://gist.github.com/Voldrix/84a01b602e5d6c53c2b67e156bf26a10).

```
#Creates an animated thumbnail of a video clip
#This script uses scene cuts instead of fixed time intervals, and does not work well for videos with few/infrequent scene cuts

numOfScenes=8 #max number of scenes
sceneLength=1.5 #length of each scene in seconds
sceneDelay=1.7 #time (seconds) after a frame cut to start scene (to avoid transition effects)

for i;do
  meta=($(ffprobe -v 0 -select_streams V:0 -show_entries stream=r_frame_rate:format=duration -of default=nw=1:nk=1 "$i"))
  framerate=$(bc <<< "scale=3;${meta[0]}/2")
  sceneSpacer=$(bc <<< "scale=3;${meta[1]}/(($numOfScenes-1)*2)") #min time between scene selection

  ffmpeg -nostdin -ss $sceneSpacer -i "$i" -vsync vfr -vf "select=if(gt(scene\,0.5)*(isnan(prev_selected_t)+gte(t-prev_selected_t\,$sceneSpacer))\,st(1\,t)*0*st(2\,ld(2)+1)\,if(ld(1)*lte(ld(2)\,$numOfScenes)\,between(t\,ld(1)+$sceneDelay\,ld(1)+$sceneDelay+$sceneLength))),scale=320:180:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease:force_divisible_by=2:flags=bicubic:sws_dither=none,framestep=2,setpts=N/($framerate*TB)" -an -sn -map_chapters -1 -map_metadata -1 -hide_banner -compression_level 5 -q:v 75 -loop 0 -f webp -y "${i%.*}".webp
done
```

Comment: What is the default compression level if you don't specify one?

Comment: Default compression level is 4.